# Images on mobile version and scaled version of website disappear

Tags: images

I have a really strange issue: Images on the mobile version and scaled version of our website are first loading correctly and then they suddenly disappear. Any clue what could have happened? Cache and gzip are disabled.

Thxs!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. retina.js was activated. Never heard from it, didn't know my template was using it (no notice anywhere). https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/retina-js/ just reverse the solution. Check if you will find retina.js (most probably at templates/mytemplate/js/) or check the url /path of the missing image. Probably it will end with @2x at the end of the image name. Insert high res images with new names or out comment  from index at your template folder.